# Put li attribut on a span

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am a beginner in the wonderful world of dev and I need help from you. Let me explain :

I have a menu that deploys when pressing on the burger and thus reveals three items .
On the one hand I am that when you click on an item the menu closes
And on the other hand I am cut the item to appear in the SPAN :)

```
$('li').click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id'));})
```

Thank you for your help. 
[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/imDesigner/6nng5z7n/3/)

Envoy Everybody

Comment: Can you explain where the problem is? the JSfiddle is pretty much working probably.

Comment: ?? no #overlay nor li in your HTML, which witch effect do you expect here ?

Comment: i want to put the ID of LI on the span and not on the alert() box ;)

Comment: ?? not even your alert can work on your fiddle , did you just copy/paste some code ?

Comment: @GCyrillus My alert box running and i juste copy the css code

Comment: @GCyrillus A id is assigned to each li ( home => id  "HOME" ) .
When the person clicks the li I would like to retrieve the id of it and displayed in the span tag

Comment: Instead of alerting just select the span and insert the ID, e.g. `$('.container span').html( $(this).attr('id') )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple as this : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nng5z7n/8/)**

added this

```
 $('li').click(function() {
   $('h1 + span').text( $(this).attr('id') )
   $('#overlay').removeClass('open');
   $('#toggle').removeClass('active');
 })
```

also removed the class `open` from `#overlay` so after you click the li the menu closes, and removed the class `active` from the button so it changes from `X` to the hamburger lines . you can exclude these two lines if you don't need them

Comment: Ahah i just do this :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You successfully got the value of the id; now you just need to get the element you want to add it to, and add it.

Instead of putting the value in an alert, you'll use the value in jquery's `text()` function (assuming that you want the ID to be inside the `<span>` tag).

First, get the `<span>` element you want:

```
$('.top')
```

This gets *all* the elements with the class "top".

Now call the `text()` function (more info here: http://api.jquery.com/text/) on the element:

```
$('.top').text('your text here');
```

Instead of *'your text here'*, put the value of the ID in, like this:

```
$('.top').text($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: Oh yeah ! I will try this one . ! Thanks !